# Ubuntu Server Samba Folder Network Share. Allow users to add files/folders but not delete them

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

So I just went through this nifty tutorial https://websiteforstudents.com/create-public-samba-share-ubuntu-17-04-17-10/

That shows how to share a network folder using Samba, without requiring any password, or login. Basically anyone on the network can access the Public folder, no login required. I followed the steps and it works. I can access the folder without having to log in.

But what I'd like to do is to give people access to add files and folders but not have privilages to delete anything from the folder. So basically they can add but not delete. How do I go about doing that? Currently testing this on a 32bit version of Ubuntu Server 16.04 running on a Virtual Machine. But plan to do this for the non VM Ubuntu server 20.04 PC. Any help?

Comment: You might want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869536/linux-directory-permissions-read-write-but-not-delete but as it is looking without user control you may not be able to achieve your desired results.  A folder permissions is what controls the permissions of the files within.  So, a folder that has a `r-x` permission will not allow for creating or deleting files.

Comment: That solution you linked is meant for user account logins and not guest logins right?

Comment: Correct.  As it is looking without user control or a user being logged in, you cannot set it so that you can create then not delete.  The parent folders usually have a `rwx`permission type which is Read, Write and Execute.  If you remove the `w` you cannot delete the file, but neither could you create one.  You cannot set Sticky bits on files without a user assigned.